# Is there any equivalent to wine for running Mac applications?

Tags: linux, mac, wine

Is there anything to run applications designed for OS X in Linux without having OSX, similar to how you can run Windows applications on Linux using Wine without having Windows?

Comment: If there were such a thing that actually worked do you think you'd have difficulty finding it?

Comment: indeed. If it's free and it works, you'd find it. If it's free but doesn't work, you don't care. If it's not free it defeats the purpose (just buy OSX).

Comment: btw you might not need to buy the most recent OSX, you could buy an older, used one (i.e. cheaper).

Comment: For what it's worth, I've heard of no such software.

Comment: Well whoever wants the 100 rep then should post "There is none" in an answer, or an answer which is actually wrong will end up getting it.

Comment: If no one manages to get 2 upvotes, there will be no accepted answer and no one will get the 100 points. It seems fair that way, especially considering the answer really is "there is none".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for an implementation of the Carbon/Cocoa frameworks used in Mac OS X.

I'm pretty sure that there doesn't exist an implementation complete enough to run Mac apps with. The only similar projects of any weight that I can find are [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/) and [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/), both of which seem to implement only portions of the Cocoa API, and even then only for cross-platform development. I would be shocked if you could run any substantial Mac program on Linux with one of these projects.

Answer (score 5):

There is [Darling](https://www.darlinghq.org/). Here are few quotes from its site:

> Darling is a translation layer that allows you to run unmodified MacOS
>   binaries on Linux. In its nature, it is similar to the well-known Wine
>   project.

...

> Darling is capable of running many console tools or
>   applications.

In the past running console apps was all it could do. But now it can run some GUI applications too:

> Does it support GUI apps?
>
> Almost! This took us a lot of time and effort, but we finally have basic 
>   experimental support for running simple graphical applications. It 
>   requires some special setup for now though, so do not expect it to work 
>   out of the box just yet. We're working on this; stay tuned!

Answer (score -3):

I have never come across a thing, but a quick google on it yielded interesting things, here's one such results [here](http://emulation.victoly.com/). Other than that, it would be interesting to see how such an emulation for a pre-Mac Intel era i.e. PowerPC can be achieved, let alone binaries for powerpc running on a x86 processor. However, since MacOSX is a derivative of BSD, why not get the sources for the macosx program that you wish to run and recompile it targeting your system?

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: It would be best to tell why this was down-voted for everyone to see. It would help others to post answers better here and better themselves also on superuser.com. Thanks for the time to read it. :)

Comment: Wine is an open-source implementation of the Win32 API, not a hardware emulator. Similarly, Macha is looking for a Linux implementation of the Mac OS X APIs, not hardware emulation for Apple hardware.

Comment: Also, Mac OS X already has PowerPC emulation software included: http://www.apple.com/rosetta/